# Rails: do we have anything built-in to output a ruby array as arguments to a javascript function call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Here's what I want, in wishful code:

#### in my controller action:

```
@javascript_function_args = [ "foo", "bar", 1, [2, 3], { :zort => 'narf', :nom => 'cake' }]
```

#### in my erb view:

```
<script … >
  performAwesome(<%= @javascript_function_args.to_js_args %>);
</script>
```

#### or, even better:

```
  <%= call_javascript_function :performAwesome, *@javascript_function_args %>
```

#### my expected output:

```
<script … >
  performAwesome("foo", "bar", 1, [2, 3], { zort : 'narf', nom : 'cake' });
</script>
```

I suppose I could just `#to_json` the array and strip the wrapping brackets, but I'm wondering if there's something more specific to handle it.

Comment: Debracketed JSON sounds fine to me. If you really don't want to muck around with the string, you could leave the brackets in and say `performAwesome.apply(window, [array-with-brackets])`.

Comment: You know, that counts as an answer, one you could get upvotes for. I like apply, but I don't remember if there's cretaceous browser support for it.

Comment: `apply` works OK as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah, the last browser to have trouble with Function.apply/call was IE 5.0, which I think we can ignore now. I didn't put it as an answer as it's more avoiding the question than answering it; my experience with Ruby is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it that doesn't involve string manipulation.

In an appropriate helper (or you could monkey-patch Array if you prefer):

```
def to_js_args(array)
  array.map {|arg| arg.to_json}.join(",")
end
```